# Effeciently querying User's name from "foreign key" ObjectId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, query-optimization, relationship

For example I have models `User` and `Post`

**User**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("pretendThisIsAUserObjectId"),
    "name": "someUser"
}
```

**Post**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("pretendThisIsAUserObjectId"),
    "title": "blah blah",
    "user_id": ObjectId("pretendThisIsAUserObjectId"),
    "content": "more blah"
}
```

User has many posts. So we have `user_id` stored in `Post`.

So when we are listing posts for each user, we will have N+1 queries (N posts plus 1 query for user's name), since we don't have join in MongoDB.

Can we also store user name in `Post`, to optimize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**. You can denormalise your data to whatever extent you feel is appropriate for your particular needs. You could even go as far to storing an entire `User` document in each `Post`, but that would be a *silly* amount of duplication.

My first inclination, however, would be to consider application-side caching of the username associated with each user ID, rather than trying to include the name in the `Post` document or querying for it each and every time you want it.

If your usernames are unique, you could consider making the username the `_id` of your `User` document, rather than the standard `ObjectId`. That makes your user IDs even more useful as you no longer need to do additional queries to find the name of each user, because their name is their ID.

Comment: great idea about storing usernames instead of ids!

Comment: is word `denormalisation` appropriate to MongoDB? I thought database normalization is only for DBs with schema and not for schemaless MongoDB

Comment: No normalisation is for databases with a schema, de-normalisation is for dbs without schema, however that being said you can de-normalise SQL techs to make them faster, this is common practice in larger sites.

Comment: I disagree, normalisation is about reducing dependency and duplication within the database, and that is a separate thing from whether or not you have a fixed schema. In fact, 10gen have said in their schema design talks to start with a normalised schema and de-normalise as appropriate to the needs of your use case. Of course, most discussion about (de)normalisation is in the context of relational databases, because Dr Codd introduced it with the relational model over 40 years ago. NoSQL is considerably younger than that

Comment: Well being a RDBA and a NoSQL DBA I can safely say I won't be applying the true logic of 3nf to MongoDB any time soon. Probably what I should of said was normally however.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Identity Map](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/identity_map.html) enabled, you can use `includes` as you normally would.

```
Post.includes(:user)...
```

See [Eager Loading](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html).

Comment: Thank you. That's helpful, but is there an option to embed user name and id, so we don't need to load whole user documents at all?